# Draw triangle VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, random, geometry, draw

Dear forum members I have to make a triangle class.

My problem is that I the public overrides sub teken does not work

**IN MY CLASS FORM (FUNCTION RANDOMSTRAAL)**

```
Private Function RandomStraal() As Int32
    Return 20 + _Random.Next(Me.ClientSize.Width\2)
End Function
```

**IN MY CLASS FORM (SUB MAAKTRIANGLE)**

```
 Private Sub MaakTriangle(x As Integer, y As Integer)
    Dim tria As New Triangle(RandomKleur, RandomKleur, New Point(x, y), New Point(x, y + RandomStraal()), New Point(x + RandomStraal(), y))
    tria.PenDikte = _Random.Next(1, 6)
    _Tekening.Add(tria)
    '_Tekening.Teken(Me.CreateGraphics)
    Invalidate()
End Sub
```

**MY CLASS TRIANGLE**

```
Friend Class Triangle
    Inherits Figuur


    Public Property Point1() As Point
    Public Property Point2() As Point
    Public Property Point3() As Point

    Private _Pointers() As Point = {Point1, Point2, Point3}

    Public Sub New(penKleur As Color, vulKleur As Color, point1 As Point, point2 As Point, point3 As Point)
        MyBase.New(penKleur, vulKleur)
        Me.Point1 = point1
        Me.Point2 = point2
        Me.Point3 = point3
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub Teken( doek As Graphics)
        Using borstel As New SolidBrush(VulKleur),
            pen As New Pen(PenKleur, PenDikte)
            Dim tria As New Rectangle(_Pointers)      **'<--the problem**
            doek.FillPolygon(borstel, tria)
            doek.DrawPolygon(pen, tria)
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

what should happen to do this work

thanks in advance

Comment: "It doesn't work" is a pretty hopeless diagnostic.  Let's assume it means "I don't see a triangle" and not "my code set my motherboard on fire".  There has to be an OnPaint() method or Paint event handler that actually calls your Teken() method.  You didn't post one so it is likely to be missing.  Override the form's OnPaint() method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems:

The Rectangle object doesn't take an array of pointers, and besides, you are trying to make a triangle, not a rectangle.  Eliminate this:

```
' Dim tria As New Rectangle(_Pointers)
```

The second problem is you are referencing the _Pointers array, but they are not updated with the new coordinates.  The points are all (0, 0):

Try it like this:

```
Public Overrides Sub Teken(doek As Graphics)
  Using borstel As New SolidBrush(VulKleur), _
        pen As New Pen(Me.PenKleur, Me.PenDikte)
    Dim myPoints() As Point = New Point() {Point1, Point2, Point3}
    doek.FillPolygon(borstel, myPoints)
    doek.DrawPolygon(pen, myPoints)
  End Using
End Sub
```

Side note: make sure you to use the Paint event of your control:

```
Private Sub Panel1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) _
                         Handles Panel1.Paint
  e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White)

  Dim tria As New Triangle(Color.Blue, Color.Red, New Point(64, 64), _
                                                  New Point(96, 96), _
                                                  New Point(32, 96))
  tria.Teken(e.Graphics)
End Sub
```

or override the OnPaint method if drawing directly on a form.